# TSQL: update a column to null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A learner here. This has to be esasy but I cannot figure it out.

I have a table like this:

```
ID -- NAME -- CHOICE
1 -- John -- book
2 -- Matt -- pen
3 -- Linda -- bag
.
.
```

What would be the script to turn all the data in column CHOICE to null?

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'd use an UPDATE statement, without a WHERE clause (so it updates every single row)

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Choice = NULL
```